# How to make the JButton execute when holding the button?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

First, my program is very simple. I just need to click or press Alt + Enter the JButton to increment the counter.

Here is the program so you can try it:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class holdDownClass implements ActionListener {
    private static JButton exebouton;
    private JTextArea ecran = new JTextArea();
    private JScrollPane scrollecran = new JScrollPane(ecran);
    private int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new holdDownClass();
    }

    private holdDownClass() {
        // Window
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Name");
        frame.setBounds(400, 350, 625, 355);
        frame.setLayout(null);

        Container container = frame.getContentPane();

        // Panel
        JPanel panneau = new JPanel();
        panneau.setLayout(null);
        panneau.setBounds(2, 42, 146, 252);
        frame.add(panneau);

        JLabel nglabel = new JLabel("Click or Press Alt+Enter");
        nglabel.setBounds(5, 0, 200, 20);
        panneau.add(nglabel);

        // Button
        exebouton = new JButton("Execute");
        exebouton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); // Shortcut: Alt + Enter
        exebouton.setBounds(4, 18, 138, 47);
        exebouton.addActionListener(this);
        panneau.add(exebouton);

        // Text Area
        ecran.setEditable(true);
        scrollecran.setBounds(150, 42, 467, 252);
        container.add(scrollecran);

        // Show
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object test = e.getSource();         
        if (test.equals(exebouton)) {
            counter += 1;
            ecran.setText(ecran.getText() + counter + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

My objective is: Instead of repetitively pressing Alt+Enter, **I want to hold Alt+Enter to increment the counter "quicker".**

Comment: Did you try handling mouse-pressed and mouse-released events. Start incrementing when mouse is pressed and stop when the mouse is released.

Comment: @Sudhanshu I didn't try. I didn't know how to. How do I do it?

Comment: for that you will have to register keyListener to the `JButton` `exebouton `

Comment: @VishalK Do you have an example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the way you can do it-

```
private boolean mousePressed;
```

And a mouse listener-

```
     exebouton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            mousePressed = true;
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    while (mousePressed) {
                        counter += 1;
                        ecran.setText(ecran.getText() + counter + "\n");
                    }
                }

            }.start();
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            mousePressed = false;
        }

    });
```

That's it.

Comment: To-the-point answer but changes to graphical components should probably be done on the EDT. Use  `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` and perhaps a check using `SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `MouseListener`, but, personally, I feel it's not the most appropriate means for achieving what it is you are trying to achieve, as it fights against the workings of the button.

Instead, you could attach a change listener to the buttons model and while the button's state remains pressed, cycle a Swing `Timer`....

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class TestButton04 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestButton04();
    }

    private int counter = 0;
    private Timer trigger;
    private JButton btn;

    public TestButton04() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                btn = new JButton("0");
                trigger = new Timer(125, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        counter++;
                        btn.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                    }
                });
                trigger.setCoalesce(true);
                trigger.setRepeats(true);

                btn.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                        if (btn.getModel().isPressed()) {
                            trigger.start();
                        } else {
                            trigger.stop();
                        }
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(btn);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you know why setting the text in the JLabel "lagging"? Even when I put 500ms delay on the timer...

Comment: Are you setting it the EDT? Are you blocking EDT?