# origin of an ActionEvent (keyboard vs mouse)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionevent

I have a continous Action which I can call by pressing down a `JButton b1`. Currently I have added a MouseListener to b1 and I control the continous nature of this action by calling `StartAction()` in `MousePressed()` and `StopAction()` in `MouseReleased()`, if the source of the mouse event happens to be b1.

Now I want to be able to trigger the button by keyboard as well. One would usually do that by ActionListeners. I can do:

```
 if (source.equals(b1)) {
 startAction();
 stopAction();
 }
```

Only problem is, this way a mouse click would trigger both the ActionListener and the mouseListener. I thought I would try setting the action listener as:

```
 if(source.equals(b1) && !(e instanceof MouseEvent))
 {
 ...
 }
```

But that gives me: *inconvertible types cannot cast MouseEvent to ActionEvent*.

So Question is: is there any way of knowing if an action event was a mouse click or an Keyboard trigger? Should I use another type of Buttons?

Comment: Instead of using a MouseListener you could use a ChangeListener to the button's model. See MadProgrammer's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697713/how-to-make-the-jbutton-execute-when-holding-the-button)

Comment: Yeah that sounds like what I want. I will try it now. Do you want to write this as an answer?

Comment: works like a charm! Feel free to add it as an answer.